# Could not decode base64 when uploading image (size: 1mb or higher)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cloudinary

I'm using cloudinary to upload and store images on my project. I'm trying to upload an image that has a size of 1mb but it gets an error "Could not decode base64". But if it smaller than 750kb it doesn't get that error. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
 if(req.body.avatar !== '') {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

        const image_id = user.avatar.public_id;

        const res = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(image_id)

        const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
            folder: 'avatars',
            width: 300,
            crop: "scale"
        })

        newUserData.avatar = {
            public_id: result.public_id,
            url: result.secure_url
        }
```

Comment: Where is req.body.avatar coming from? Are you sure it's a valid Base64 encoded file? Cloudinary supports sending files of up to 60 MB as a base64 encoded string, so if it's failing there may be something else causing the larger files to be truncated or not encoded correctly before they're sent to Cloudinary's API

Comment: @Igy I am able to successfully upload images less than 750kb in my web project and it stores the uploaded image in cloudinary. I'm not sure why it fails whenever I upload an image larger than that

Comment: @Igy also req.body.avatar comes from an image uploaded in frontend.

Comment: There must be some difference between the value of req.body.avatar when you upload the smaller file to Cloudinary and the larger one; from what you've said, I'm guessing it's in how the data was passed to your backend, but certainly it's possible to upload such files to Cloudinary via either base64 encoding, or as a standard multipart form upload of the file's bytes

Comment: @Igy this is the code in our frontend when getting the images, im not sure if the problem is still in the frontend part  

`const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
            if(reader.readyState === 2){
                setAvatarPreview(reader.result)
                setAvatar(reader.result)
            }
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])`

Comment: `<input 
                                                        type="file" 
                                                        id="avatar" 
                                                        name="avatar" 
                                                        accept="images/*"
                                                        onChange={onChange}
                                                        style={{width: '90%'}}
                                                    />`

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same issue . Just send the bas64 file  as json and not as formData .
step 1 : `app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" })); app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));`

step 2 : since you are converting the image on onChange event the  file is converted to base64 . so just send that data as json .

Comment: i came up with same error but this is not fixing the problem  what might be the cause